# Moving a high quality line on a panel c#

Tags: c#, system.drawing, windows

I want to draw a line on a panel and then move it as the mouse moves. To do so, I draw the line and when the mouse moves I redraw the line to the new location and remove the previous line by drawing a line with the background color on it. It works fine if I do not use the high quality smoothing mode. But if use high quality smoothing mode, it leave traces on the panel. Does anybody know how to fix this? Thank you. 
Here is the code

```
        int x_previous = 0;
        int y_previous = 0;

        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen pen1 = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Black, 3);
            Pen pen2 = new System.Drawing.Pen(panel1.BackColor, 3);
            Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.DrawLine(pen2, new Point(0, 0), new Point(x_previous, y_previous));
            g.DrawLine(pen1, new Point(0, 0), new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y));
            x_previous = e.Location.X;
            y_previous = e.Location.Y;
        }
```

Here is the snapshot with SmoothingMode

[image: Snapshot of the results]

Here is the snapshot without SmoothingMode

[image: Snapshot of the results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of drawing a line over a line, the safest option would be to clear the graphics using `g.Clear(panel1.BackColor)`. This will wipe everything off that has been drawn, so that you can safely draw a new line:

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Pen pen1 = new System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Black, 3);
    Pen pen2 = new System.Drawing.Pen(panel1.BackColor, 3);
    Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
    // Clear the graphics, creating a blank area to draw on
    g.Clear(panel1.BackColor);
    g.DrawLine(pen1, new Point(0, 0), new Point(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y));
    x_previous = e.Location.X;
    y_previous = e.Location.Y;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the better way unless there's some other weird reason to not clear the area.  I'm not familiar enough to know if there's a performance benefit to only drawing over the line, but if there is I'd guess it's small enough to not worry about.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing the line in the event handler for the mouse movement you should use it to [Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) the panel and perform the line drawing in a handler for its [Paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) event. There will be no need to erase the old line.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used WinForms in a while, so you'll have to forgive me if this doesn't work.

I assume that anti-aliasing has slightly blurred the edges of the line so that the initial line extends slightly further out than the width of the pen.  That also means that the edges of the white pen won't be completely opaque when drawing over the black line.

Try increasing the width of the white pen until it completely covers the black, and maybe see if you can leave the Graphics object with lower quality rendering  for the white pen, and use the smoothing only for the black pen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had tried this before, it works for the line but still leaves some residues behind at the end of the line.

Comment: Did you try further increasing the width of the white pen?  You may also have to do a little vector maths to extend the points you're drawing the white line between.